# Urgent restore files after using delete_files on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, windows, codeigniter, recovery

I tried to delete an image in my website using CodeIgniter using this command:

```
delete_files("./".$versus->getConc1() -> getPicture_path());
```

I need to know how to recover my files, I use Windows 8 and EasyPHP.

Comment: This is likely to run a system delete command, not a GUI recycle feature. Thus, you'll probably need to try disk recovery software. Don't install one on the same drive, incidentally, since you may overwrite the files you are intending to recover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `EasyPHP` was installed to another drive then your system drive (`C:` is usually your system drive and `D:` is your storage drive), you just need to install a recovery software.

**NOTE:** It is very important not to write/delete/copy on that partition/drive. Otherwise your information might be lost!

I usually take the drive out, install it into another PC which has every software/windows service disabled that could write on that drive. Example: windows update, windows system restore, virtual memory, superfetch, antivirus, etc.

**LE:** Don't forget to always backup your files if you are working on something important. I do daily backups and store those backups on another PC. If the development PC crashes in some way, I always have the backup from yesterday.

Take a look at [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/54210/are-there-any-good-free-undelete-tools-for-windows).

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your recycle bin? Or if you are using SVN take it from the previous check in.

Comment: Try looking for a disk recovery software.... you should be able to recover back the deleted data.